# Element screenshot is not captured correctly in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ashot

I am trying to capture one canvas section screenshot using selenium.I have used the element's location to capture the screenshot as below. Unfortunately, I am not getting the section image as expected. I can observe more differences in the actual and expected image.In the below Screenshot, Green Color box is indicating the expected one and Red Color box is indicating the actual One.

[image: enter code here]

I have tried with the below two approaches, but both are resulting the same.

**Approach 1:**

```
public void captureSectionScreenshot(WebDriver driver){

    try{
        WebElement canvasElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("canvas"));
        System.out.println("Map X"+canvasElement.getLocation().getX());
        System.out.println("Map Y"+canvasElement.getLocation().getY());

        // Get entire page screenshot
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        BufferedImage fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
        // Get the location of element on the page
        Point point = canvasElement.getLocation();
        // Get width and height of the element
        int eleWidth = canvasElement.getSize().getWidth();
        int eleHeight = canvasElement.getSize().getHeight();

        BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage( point.getX(), point.getY(),
                eleWidth, eleHeight);
        ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
        // Copy the Section screenshot to disk
        File screenshotLocation = new File("***********************************\\CanvasScreenshot.png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error is Occured :"+e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

**Approach 2: (using AShot)**

```
public void captureScreenshot(WebDriver driver){

    String actualOutputImagePath="**************************\AShot_CanvasScreenshot.png";
    WebElement canvasElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("canvas"));
    Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().coordsProvider(
            new WebDriverCoordsProvider()).takeScreenshot(driver,canvasElement);
    BufferedImage actualImage = screenshot.getImage();

    try{
        ImageIO.write(actualImage, "png", new File(actualOutputImagePath));

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map" class="map">
    <div class="ol-viewport" data-view="3" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; touch-action: none;">
        <canvas class="ol-unselectable" width="268" height="500" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"></canvas>
        <div class="ol-overlaycontainer"></div>
        <div class="ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the html? I suspect that is by canvas tagname

Comment: HTML is added in the question